# Swift Search Bar Tint Color Not Correct

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I have set the search bar tint color to a custom color in Interface Builder as so:

[image]

But when I load up the app in the simulator it appears like this:

[image]

Translucent box is left unticked, so any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try to set the color via code?

Comment: Yep, tried just using standard UIColor.orangeColor() as well and gave the same effect then too.

Comment: would you allow me to try it myself? I would need RGBA then

Comment: I can't give you access to the repo, if that's what you're asking, company policy I'm afraid.

Comment: No i dont want the repo, just the RGB for the color you're trying to use because i tried a few colors now and can't reproduce your problem

Comment: Oh okay sorry, its #01707f but I have tried many colors, even in code the pre-set orangeColor, blackColor etc. and the problem still persists.